# How to make NLog thread-safely write to separate file target at runtime?

Tags: c#, multithreading, nlog

I have an application which runs many threads (~50), every thread acquires a payment with lock to be processed from a database, and then processes it.
However, 50 threads make logs unreadable, mixed up and of enormous filesize.
Now, I want to make NLog write to a separate file for every payment ID, so that all history on payment processment is stored in one file.

NLog configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets>
    <target name="file" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" queueLimit="10000" overflowAction="Discard">
      <target name="f" xsi:type="File" fileName="C:\LogFiles\Immediate\${shortdate}.server.log" layout="${longdate}|${level}|${processid}|${threadid}|${level:upperCase=true}|${callsite:className=false}|${message}" encoding="utf-8"/>
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

My code now:

```
private static readonly ILogger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger(); // "2017-07-20.log"

while (!_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    using (var session = _connectionFactory.GetSession())
    {
        AcquirePaymentWithUpdlockReadpast(session, 
            Logger,  // "2017-07-20.log" 
            payment => {
                if (payment == null)
                    return;

                Logger.Debug($"Payment {payment.Id} has been acquired for processment");

                ProcessPayment(session, Logger, payment); // "2017-07-20.log"
            });
    }

    Thread.Sleep(50);
}
```

What I expect it to be:

```
private static readonly ILogger GeneralLogger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger(); // "2017-07-20.General.log"

while (!_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    using (var session = _connectionFactory.GetSession())
    {
        AcquirePaymentWithUpdlockReadpast(session, 
            GeneralLogger, // "2017-07-20.General.log"
            payment => {
                if (payment == null)
                    return;

                var paymentLogger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
                paymentLogger.FileName = $"Payment-{payment.Id}.log"; // <-- I want this. 
                paymentLogger.Debug($"Payment has been acquired for processment");

                ProcessPayment(session, paymentLogger, payment); // "2017-07-20.Payment-123.log"
            });
    }

    Thread.Sleep(50);
}
```

I have found some solutions which use `LogManager.Configuration`, but it doesn't seem to be thread-safe.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets>
    <target name="file" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" queueLimit="10000" overflowAction="Discard">
      <target name="f" xsi:type="File" fileName="C:\LogFiles\Immediate\${shortdate}.server.log" layout="${longdate}|${level}|${processid}|${threadid}|${level:upperCase=true}|${callsite:className=false}|${message}" encoding="utf-8"/>
    </target>
    <target name="paymentFile" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" queueLimit="10000" overflowAction="Discard">
      <target name="p" xsi:type="File" fileName="C:\LogFiles\Immediate\Payment-${event-properties:PaymentID:whenEmpty=0}.log" layout="${longdate}|${level}|${processid}|${threadid}|${level:upperCase=true}|${callsite:className=false}|${message}" encoding="utf-8"/>
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="paymentFile">
         <condition="'${event-properties:PaymentID:whenEmpty=0}'!='0'" action="LogFinal" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Then you can do the logging like this (Can be improved with NLog-Fluent):

```
LogEventInfo theEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Debug, $"Payment has been acquired for processment");
theEvent.Properties["PaymentID"] = payment.Id;
Logger.Debug(theEvent);
```

**Alternative solution could be like this:**

```
var paymentLogger = LogManager.GetLogger($"Payment-{payment.Id}");
paymentLogger.Debug($"Payment has been acquired for processment")
```

And then change the logger-filter to this:

```
<logger name="Payment-*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="paymentFile" />
```

And then change paymentFile filename to this:

```
fileName="C:\LogFiles\Immediate\{logger}.log"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The second approach did help me, I did never know I can use logger name this way. However, I have found a little shorter solution with `name` property, it may be interesting to you :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Rolf Kristensen's answer, I have used the second approach, but have found a similar, but shorter solution which uses `name` property:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets>
    <target name="all" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" queueLimit="10000" overflowAction="Discard">
      <target name="f" xsi:type="File" fileName="C:\LogFiles\${shortdate}.All.log" layout="${longdate}|${level}|${processid}|${threadid}|${level:upperCase=true}|${callsite:className=false}|${message}" encoding="utf-8"/>
    </target>
    <target name="perLoggerName" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" queueLimit="10000" overflowAction="Discard">
      <target name="f" xsi:type="File" fileName="C:\LogFiles\${shortdate}.${logger}.log" layout="${longdate}|${level}|${processid}|${threadid}|${level:upperCase=true}|${callsite:className=false}|${message}" encoding="utf-8"/>
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="all"/>
    <logger name="Document-*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="perLoggerName"/>
    <logger name="Job-*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="perLoggerName"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Consider adding openFileCacheSize="25" and openFileCacheTimeout="600" to the file-target wrapped under "perLoggerName" (Because you will get a pending file-state for each logger-name). Consider renaming the file-target wrapped under "perLoggerName" to "p" (instead of "f").